# Evaluating implicit functions numerically

Tags: newton-raphson, implicit-function

A simple question.

Are there any methods on how to evaluate an implicit function f(x,y) = 0 numerically?

Does one fix one of the variables and then use newtons method or similar on f(x0,y) and then iterate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I suppose that* **evaluate** *stands for* **solve**.

What you can do is to consider that you want to minimize $$\Phi=\frac 12\left[f(x,y)\right]^2$$ (hoping, for sure, that you will get zero as the final result !).

Then, since you look for the minimum, you have to solve
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x}=f(x,y)\,\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}=f(x,y)\,\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$$ and, just as in Newton method, use Taylor expansions truncated to first orders. So, you have two linear equations for two unknown variables.

Just search for *function minimization* (this is wide domain).

Comment: Than you very much! Sorry for the late reply, my computer crashed yesterday..

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the problem to a differential equation where the initial condition follows from one particular solution for $y$ for one particular $x$. Given some arbitrary pair $(x,y)$ for which you have $f(x,y) = 0$, you can find a new infinitesimally shifted solution pair $(x+\delta x,y + \delta y)$, by demanding that $f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y) = 0$. To first order in $\delta x$ and $\delta y$, we then have:

$$f(x,y) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \delta x +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \delta y \approx 0 $$

Using $f(x,y) = 0$, we get:

$$\dfrac{\delta y}{\delta x} \approx -\frac{ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} }{ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} }$$

In the limit of $\delta x \to 0$ the l.h.s. becomes the derivative of y w.r.t. x and the relation becomes exact:

$$\dfrac{d y}{d x} =-\frac{ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} }{ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} }$$

You thus have an ordinary differential equation that you can solve numerically using standard methods.